# Add same object to multiple arraylists

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a game and noticed that adding an object to two arraylists and then updating one of them doesn't update the other. Is it possible to solve this?

I have a list of all tiles which is looped though when rendering. But I also want a list of slots(extends Tile) in my inventory class instead of looping though all game tiles to get the inventory slots.

I have two lists: Game.tiles and Inventory.slots

This is where I add slots (Inventory class):

```
for(int i = 0; i< 16; i++){
Slot slot = new Slot();
Game.tiles.add(slot);
slots.add(slot);
}
```

And this is where I modify slots (Inventory class):

```
for(int i = 0; i< 16; i++){
slots.get(i).visable = false;
}
```

The problem is that the data updates for the slot in the slots list but not for the same slot in the Game.tiles list.

Full inventory class: http://pastebin.com/KS5BNB3F

Comment: Add the same instance to both array lists?

Comment: nope... if the object is the same then you have in every list the references of it.... modifing the object in list A will affect the only one instance... post the code

Comment: show us what aer you doing....

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions. It is unclear without seeing code what you are asking.

Comment: Just because a class extends another one does not mean that `instances` of the superclass know anything about completely different `instances` of the subclass. You question demonstrates a fundamental lack of comprehension that is too broad to address on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an object to two different `ArrayList`, you are actually adding only references to the object. So if you modify the object, it will reflect in both the lists at the same time. See the following code snippet:

```
public class Clazz{
   private Integer d = 0;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Clazz obj = new Clazz();
       List<Clazz> list1 = new ArrayList<Clazz>();
       List<Clazz> list2 = new ArrayList<Clazz>();
       list1.add(obj);
       list2.add(obj);
       obj.d = 15;
       System.out.println(list1.get(0).d); //prints 15
       System.out.println(list2.get(0).d); //prints 15
   }
}
```

Comment: I've changed my code to this but it still doesn't seem to work:                        `for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {  
   Slot slot = new Slot(100 + (i * 64), 900, true);  
   Game.tiles.add(slot);  
   slots.add(slot);  
  }` Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are adding 16 different `Slot` objects to both `Game.tiles` and `slots`. Let's say if you modify slot object 5, it will be reflected in both of these lists. Is it not happening with you?

Comment: No unfortunely not. Maybe it's something with that the first list is for tiles and the second for slots?If I do edit the Game.tiles list then it affectes rendering but not if I change the slots list.  EDIT: I tested it with System.out.println(Game.tiles.get(i+2).visable + ", " + slots.get(i).visable); and they really have different data (+2 because there are two others tiles)

Comment: VHS some more help would be appreciated

Comment: @mcrafterzz, can you edit your question and show the full code of your method?

Comment: full code of which methoud? The inventory class? EDIT: Here is the full inventory class: http://pastebin.com/KS5BNB3F

Comment: @MCrafterzz, how do you expect me or anyone to help here? The code you have shown in the question is different from the one in your link above. In the code in the link, you are not even showing how `slots` is populated. You need to show minimal and yet verifiable code for anyone here to help you.

Comment: I've tried to create some minimal code but I can't replicate it. I though for a while that the problem was that one was static but the other one wasen't but that wasen't the case. Do you have any idea what could cause this behavier. Also would it help if I uploaded the whole souce code?

Comment: @MCrafterzz, without looking at the code that was not working, I can only make guesses. But now since it is resolved, there is no point to look back. The important thing to learn here is that when you add the same object to two different lists, you are actually adding a reference to the object and hence if you modify it in one list, it automatically reflects in the other.

Comment: I manages to solve the problem in the code. It accually didn't have anything with multiple lists to do the problem was that I made a big mistake in Tile class constructer. This: ``public Tile(Image image, int x, int y, int size) {
  new Tile(image, x, y, size, size, true, 0);
 }`` Instead of ``public Tile(Image image, int x, int y, int size) {
  this(image, x, y, size, size, true, 0);
 }`` Thanks for all amazing help!

Answer (score -1):

Create an object instance, add it to both arrays. Then those arrays will have the same references. This means that updating your object would result in it updated in both arrays.